# Sql CLR function row as input

Tags: sqlclr

I am attempting to create a CLR Hashing function that I can use in Sql.

What I am looking to do is calculate the `md5 checksum` value of a row. How do I define that the input to the function should be a row?

For example, the Sql native checksum function takes 'expression' as a parameter, which allows you to call it as:

```
Select CHECKSUM(*) From dbo.SomeTable
```

What signature do I define in C# so that it can take `*` as a parameter?

Comment: did you figure it out? is it possible?

Comment: @mishkin: no, it is not possible. I added an answer with more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible in SQLCLR.

The SQLCLR interface does not allow for a few of the constructs that are found in several of the internal T-SQL functions, namely:

1. Passing in "*" as the input parameter
    EXAMPLE: CHECKSUM(*)
    EXAMPLE: BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)
2. Optional input parameters for the same function name
    EXAMPLE: CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-04-20', 101) vs CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-04-20)
    EXAMPLE: CHARINDEX('o', 'bob', 3) vs CHARINDEX('o', 'bob')
3. Returning different datatypes for the same function name
    EXAMPLE: CONVERT(INT, '12') vs CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-04-20')
    EXAMPLE: COALESCE(@IntVariable, 12) vs COALESCE(@VarcharVariable, 'test')

Essentially, there is no overloading of function names.

Comment: Thank you. That is upsetting since that eliminates a lot of the usefulness of clr udfs